# Nginx: split_clients for multi-vhost server?

Tags: nginx, vhosts

Question: Is `split_client` universal for all virtual hosts configured under `http`, or one physical server?

My understanding is that the `split_client` directive goes under the `http` block. I tested it, and it works as described [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html).

I also set up multiple `server` blocks (i.e. virtual hosts) under `http`, in order to run multiple sites. The multiple sites are working, but I am wondering if you can have separate `split_clients` for each vhosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split_client` has `http` context so it can be configured for all server blocks (virtual hosts). But you can use split variables in particular server blocks only, so others server blocks can work as usual, w/o A/B.

Official tutorial (split with different upstreams): [Performing A/B Testing with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/performing-a-b-testing-nginx-plus/)

Good DO tutorial (split with different index files): [How To Target Your Users with Nginx Analytics and A/B Testing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-target-your-users-with-nginx-analytics-and-a-b-testing)

Comment: So, you're saying it is universal for all `server` blocks, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is universal, but you can use it or no in different server blocks.

Comment: I'm curious, is `split_clients` typically used like a load balancer where a `redirect` is used to route traffic to a different/sub-domain (in the "Partial App Tests" section: https://www.viget.com/articles/split-test-traffic-distribution-with-nginx)? My understand from reading was that `split_clients` is for setting more like variables/parameters, and you can use the typically load balancer setup ("Full App Tests" section from link) for routing traffic.

Comment: `split_clients` typically used like a A/B test tool :) This is not load balancing. But you can try it for LB, just for fun. About true LB: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html